# How to extract notes from Google Slides and insert into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to extract the notes from a Google Slide deck and insert them into a Google Sheet.

I found code to do this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACzlr_oD6qU). With a couple of slight modifications, here is the code:

```
function speakerNotes() {
  const slides = SlidesApp.openById('1VmtdJD3caUNADGF-eAYV09oPaem1s9WMy5Xut767wGs').getSlides();
  const allNotes = [];
  slides.map((slide, index) => {
    const note = slide.getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape().getText().asString();
  allNotes.push([index + 1+') ' ,note.replace('\n','')]);
  });
  console.log(allNotes)
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vmnpQ3rpUtWQobLTSG4MDCCHMhHoKoIygRWEYt-RYXU');
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Speaker Notes')
  sheet.getRange(1,1,allNotes.length,allNotes[0].length).setValues(allNotes)
  sheet.autoResizeColumns(1,2)
}
```

The code isn't pulling out the notes that are in the slide. Instead, I'm getting this in my Google sheet:

[image: screenshot of output in Google Sheet]

Any help would be appreciated!

********UPDATE
I've corrected my code with the suggested edit and one of my own. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getText` is a method of `TextRange`.  You are missing the parenthesis `()`

Replace

```
const note = slide.getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape().getText.toString();
```

With

```
const note = slide.getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape().getText().toString();
```

Comment: Brilliant detective work! Thank you. I also replaced the toString with asString. It now works!

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to extract the notes in HTML so that the formatting is preserved.

Comment: It's not HTML but instead it is a series of Runs with various formats.  You would have to translate the Runs into HTML.  See [TextRange.getRuns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getRuns())

Comment: Thank you. Before I try to understand TextRange.getRuns() (I'm a newbie...), would using this result in an output in my Google Sheet that has HTML tags for the formatting that was in the slide notes (e.g. bulleted lists, bold, italics, etc.)? That's ultimately what I'm trying to get to -- text with HTML tags, because it will then be imported into a third-party platform, which will recognize the tags and format it accordingly. Trying to do this at scale, thus the script.

Comment: You are talking about a translator from Google Slides styling to HTML. No easy task.

Comment: Thank you. I may have to give up that dream, then.