# Need script to extract from Google Slide notes and put into Google sheets with HTML tags

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have a use case where I need to extract notes from Google Slides and put them into a Google Sheet with HTML tags. This has been a manual process, but it needs to go to scale.

Here is an example of notes from a Google Slide (to be extracted, with HTML formatting):

[image]

The bold headers are standard and always the same. I want the script to:

1. Extract the notes from each slide in the deck.
2. Recognize the headers and parse the notes into 3 chunks (Comments, Notes to Instructor, and Notes to Student).
3. Insert the notes into a Google sheet (see screenshot below) with HTML tags for formatting, 1 row for each slide.

Here is what the desired end result would look like:

[image]

I already have code for extracting notes and inserting them into a Google Sheet. It doesn't parse the notes into the three chunks and it doesn't add HTML tags. Here is that code:

```
function speakerNotes() {
    const slides = SlidesApp.openById([insert source Google Slides ID]).getSlides();
    const allNotes = [];

    slides.map((slide, index) => {
      const note = slide.getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape().getText().asString();

    allNotes.push([index + 1 ,note.replace('\n','')]);
    });
    console.log(allNotes)

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById([insert target Google Sheet ID]);
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Speaker Notes')
    sheet.getRange(1,1,allNotes.length,allNotes[0].length).setValues(allNotes)
    sheet.autoResizeColumns(1,2)

    }
```

I know this is likely a very complicated script, if it's even possible. Any thoughts for how to do this are welcome (for example, maybe there's an interim step, like downloading a PDF of the slide deck with notes and going from there).

Here is a [sample slide deck](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/18ild1vwuTmprmhqKTiBsTnn3hY0mEn5kjXFRT0WrT1A/copy).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract notes from Google Slides and insert into Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890633/how-to-extract-notes-from-google-slides-and-insert-into-google-sheets)

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you. That post was from me. Your comments in that post helped me refine the script in this post (that extracts text from the notes in a slide). In that post, you also suggested using TextRange.getRuns() to address the HTML issue. I've researched that and using it is beyond my coding abilities. I've crafted this post to articulate the full problem that I'm hoping to solve, which includes the parsing of comments into chunks and adding HTML tags. I know it's a big ask, but I'm hoping for code that does those things.